# How to open protected files from LG devices?

Tags: encryption, lg, files

I sold my LG G4 and I used the content lock on my files. Now, I switched my mobile to Huawei P8 Lite, but the files which were protected from my LG G4 couldn't be opened, and their format is some 'dm files'.

How to open these files?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the LG phone system encryption tool for protecting your content , then it can only be unlocked from the same device.

Answer (score 0):

To unlock files locked via the LG Gallery app, you have to do the following:

1. Get any LG phone. Doesn't matter what model, it just has to have the "lock" feature.
2. set up the Google account you used on the previous LG (the one you used for locking the content)
3. Set the "lock" feature (if not done already) and make sure the Google account you set up is used for the lock (Settings - Security - Content lock). You can set the lock by simply locking any file.
4. Copy the locked files you with to open over to the phone.
5. Gallery > Show locked files > Unlock > Done